# T460S Fingerprint enroll

Tags: release-hera

I'm trying to get my fingerprint reader for my T460S but when i try fprintd-enroll it says no readers found.

I did install the validity-sensors-tools snap and my LED on my fingerprint reader does seem to flash but i just cannot enroll.

I did also install the fingerprint-gui and ran it as sudo but no readers found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my T480s with the fingerprint 06cb:009a which has no support on the libfprint. I believe the following solution could work for you as the T460s also uses a fingerprint reader from the *Validity Sensors Inc*. I made it work going through a series of tutorials that lead me to this:

- **Setup [python-validity](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity)** (which is an alternative project that implemented this fingerprint reader)

```
$ sudo apt remove fprintd
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
...wait a bit...
```

- **Register your fingers**

```
$ fprintd-enroll
$ fprintd-verify
```

- **Login configuration for Elementary OS** (following some instructions from [Arch Linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Configuration))

Add `pam_fprintd.so` as *sufficient* to the top of the auth section of teh following files:

```
/etc/pam.d/common-session
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
/etc/pam.d/common-session
/etc/pam.d/common-password
```

*Example:*

```
auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
...
```

For me, these are the files the covered most of the authentication places like, sudo, login, admin requests. Anyway, you can try to change other files in the pam.d folder to match your needs.